# Converter doesn't work and not taken by criteria

Tags: converters, criteria-api

i'm new here^^

i'm working with a db in which boolean are registered as VARCHAR(3) So i made a converter :

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter
public class BooleanToStringConverter implements
    AttributeConverter<Boolean, String> {

@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Boolean value) {
    if (value == null)
        return "";
    else if (value)
        return "OUI";
    else
        return "NON";

}

@Override
public Boolean convertToEntityAttribute(String value) {
    if (value == null)
        return null;
    else if (value.trim().equals("OUI"))
        return true;
    else if (value.trim().equals("NON"))
        return false;
    else if (value.trim().equals(""))
        return null;
    else
        throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid boolean character: "
                + value);
}
}
```

i put my annotations  @Convert:

```
public class Institution extends AbstractHREntity {

@Column(name = "IDOU00")
private String code;
@Column(table = "ZEXX", name = "LBOULG")
private String libelle;
@Column(table = "ZEXX", name = "LBOUSH")
private String abreviation;
@Column(table = "ZEYY", name = "LIBEXL")
private String libelleLong;
@Convert(converter = BooleanToStringConverter.class)
@Column(table = "ZEZZ", name = "ESTBUDGET", length = 3)
private Boolean isBudget;[/CODE]
```

But when i do a request with a criteria :

```
public List<Institution> findInstitutions(RechercheInstitutionData datas) throws DaoException{
    List<Institution> resultList = new ArrayList<Institution>();
    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Institution.class, "institution");

    if(null!=datas.getInstitutionSearched())
    {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(datas.getInstitutionSearched().getLibelleLong())){
            criteria.add(Restrictions.like("institution.libelleLong", datas.getInstitutionSearched().getLibelleLong().toUpperCase(), MatchMode.START));             
        }
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(datas.getInstitutionSearched().getAbreviation())){
            criteria.add(Restrictions.like("institution.abreviation", datas.getInstitutionSearched().getAbreviation().toUpperCase(), MatchMode.START));             
        }
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(datas.getInstitutionSearched().getLibelle())){
            criteria.add(Restrictions.like("institution.libelle", datas.getInstitutionSearched().getLibelle(), MatchMode.START).ignoreCase());              
        }
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(datas.getInstitutionSearched().getCode())){
            criteria.add(Restrictions.like("institution.code", datas.getInstitutionSearched().getCode(), MatchMode.START));             
        }
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("institution.code"));
    }
    resultList = find(criteria);
    return resultList;
}
```

i had this error that occurred :

```
10:25:31,172 INFO  [RechercheInstitution.beans.RechercheInstitutionBean] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-5) --> findInstitutions()
10:25:32,549 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-5) Hibernate: select this_.NUDOSS as NUDOSS1_35_0_, this_.IDOU00 as IDOU2_35_0_, this_1_.TBUDGE as TBUDGE1_39_0_, this_2_.LIBEXL as LIBEXL1_37_0_, this_3_.LBOUSH as LBOUSH1_36_0_, this_3_.LBOULG as LBOULG2_36_0_ from ZE00 this_ left outer join ZEWD this_1_ on this_.NUDOSS=this_1_.NUDOSS left outer join ZE04 this_2_ on this_.NUDOSS=this_2_.NUDOSS left outer join ZE01 this_3_ on this_.NUDOSS=this_3_.NUDOSS where this_3_.LBOUSH like ? order by this_.IDOU00 asc

10:25:33,310 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-5) SQL Error: -99999, SQLState: 07006
10:25:33,311 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-5) Data type mismatch. (For input string: "OUI")
10:25:33,313 ERROR [RechercheInstitution.ejb.institution.InstitutionMgrBean] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-5) InstitutionMgrBean.findInstitutions : common_HR.exception.DaoException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
10:25:33,315 INFO  [RechercheInstitution.beans.RechercheInstitutionBean] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-5) <-- findInstitutions()
```

It looks like it doesn't use my converter, i tried breakpoints it doesn't go into my converter... In converter doc it says "all you have to do is put the @convert" but apparently no... Please help i'm really lost.